# How I send tether token on metamask?

Tags: erc-20, metamask, cpp-ethereum, usdt

I have 1053 USDT and 0.0028 ETH in my metamask wallet.

I want to send 1000 USDT to other address but I faced "Insufficient funds." for ETH.

So, I think I can swap 53 USDT to ETH. But faced same error..

It would be appreciated if anyone could help me.

Thanks.

Comment: i think u have not enough ether to pay the transaction fees

Comment: u need to transfer some ether to ur account and then send 1000USDT

Comment: Hi, Majd. Thanks for your help.. So How can i get some ether from USDT I have? James

Comment: no sadly you need to buy eth from somewhere else (binance or KeCoin) and then transfer them to your wallet (will cost you money). and then you can send your USDT

Comment: Hi, Majd, Could you please send me 0.01 ETH? I will send you 100 USDT. Thanks for your help. James.

Comment: Sorry I can’t :(

Comment: :) Okay No problem. Anyway I appreciate your help. Thanks again.. Have a good day.

Comment: If sending ether is not possible by u, then u need to wait for a minute where gas fees are very very very low :(

Comment: Perfect, If I can send.. Could you please let me know the way?

Comment: like Hristo Todorov said -> https://etherscan.io/gastracker you could try when ERC20 Transfer Average cost less than what you have in ether  0.0028 * ether-price (but it changes very quickly). And be careful if you pay a low/avg fee then your tx could be stuck. However, it is the only way if you don't have ether or you will never transfer more ether for some reason to this account.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short is either you wait until the gas prices are realy low or you send some more ETH to make the transactions possible.

**Here you can check the gas prices** - https://etherscan.io/gastracker

[image]
On the picture above you can see the Low/Average/High price for the to type of transactions you are trying to do. Currently 1 ETH = 3,760.96$ and your 0.0028ETH = 10$ so there is no way to make any of the transactions you want.

Comment: Hi, Hristo Todorov, I apprecite your help. How can I get some eth? Is it possible to get eth from USDT?

Comment: You can get ETH from USDT only throughout swap which you can not perfom. The other way is to send some ETH to your address. The same way you got ETH in your address initially.